# Bootstrap two columns to align

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get 4 columns to align with two that are in a form but for the life of me i can't see what I'm doing wrong.

This is the code:

```
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="inputText3" class="col-6 col-sm-3 col-form-label text-sm-right">Address</label>
              <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-6">
                <input id="inputText3" type="text" class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="inputText3" class="col-6 col-sm-3 col-form-label text-sm-right">Phone</label>
              <div class="col-3 col-sm-3">
                <input id="inputText3" type="text" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <label for="inputText3" class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-form-label text-sm-right">Gender</label>
              <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                <select class="form-control">
                  <option value="Male" selected>Male</option>
                  <option value="Female">Female</option>
                </select>
              </div>
          </div>
```

The end result I would like is for the bottom four to be aligned nicely with the top one.

[image]

Comment: You want your "Male" selector to be where Gender label is now?

Comment: Do you have other CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the 4 form elements properly align with the 2 form elements that precede them, you just have to make sure that the sum of the column units used for the 4 elements equals the sum of the column units used for the 2 form elements that precede them.

And you have to make sure that this happens **at every breakpoint**.

This is best explained by looking at the column classes in the code snippet below.

And to ensure that there is some margin between phone and gender on the smallest screens (when they stack up), I added the `mb-3` class (margin-bottom 3 units) to the phone column.

Click "run code snippet" below and expand to full page for testing:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputText3" class="col-6 col-sm-3 col-form-label text-sm-right">Address</label>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-6">
            <input id="inputText3" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputText3" class="col-2 col-sm-3 col-form-label text-sm-right mb-3">Phone</label>
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-3">
            <input id="inputText3" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <label for="inputText3" class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 col-form-label text-sm-right">Gender</label>
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-3 col-lg-2">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option value="Male" selected>Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```